# Give PHP permission to open Microsoft Word in IIS7

Tags: php, iis-7, ms-word

I have a PHP application that needs to access Microsoft Word on an IIS7 server using the COM library.  I have tried this link: http://www.orbis-software.com/knowledge-base/viewArticle.php?id=402, and restarted the server after but PHP still doesn't have permission to open Word.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You probably need to apply permisions on the user IIS/ Your application pool is runing under. Do you have any specific errors?

Comment: @Mathieu de Lorimier Where can I check errors from